# Property '__persistor' does not exist on type 'Store<any, AnyAction>'

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

I try put togeter a client side redux persistent store, as docs here recommend:

https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper

```js
// pages/_app.tsx
import React from 'react';
import App from 'next/app';
import {useStore} from 'react-redux';
import {wrapper} from './lib/redux';
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

export default wrapper.withRedux(({Component, pageProps}) => {
  const store = useStore();
  return (
    <PersistGate persistor={store.__persistor} loading={<div>Loading</div>}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </PersistGate>
  );
});
```

But get following error:

```
./pages/_app.tsx:40:39
Type error: Property '__persistor' does not exist on type 'Store<any, AnyAction>'.

  38 |           <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
  39 |         </Head>
> 40 |         <PersistGate persistor={store.__persistor} loading={<div>Loading</div>}>
     |                                       ^
  41 |           <Component {...pageProps} />
  42 |         </PersistGate>
  43 |         <CookieDialog />
```

What is wrong? Is this a compatibility issue? Have these versions.

```
"redux": "^4.1.1",
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
"redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
```

I also not understand the next coming part, why those parameters I need in the `page`? What is this `connect` method? Do I really need?

```js
// pages/index.js
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

export default connect(state => state, {setClientState})(({fromServer, fromClient, setClientState}) => (
  <div>
```

This is how `__persistor` is assigned in `store.ts`.

```js
    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, combinedReducer);

    const store: any = configureStore({
      reducer: persistedReducer,
      devTools: true,
    });

    store.__persistor = persistStore(store);

    return store;
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?

Comment: In app.tsx I forget to apply the `wrapper.withRedux` method, so need: `export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);`